# BeautifulSoup / lxml race condition

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have what seems to be a race condition on my remote server... that I cannot reproduce with a simple command line example (great start to a question, I know). But it is very consistently wrong and I cannot figure out why. I have tried Googling, but the only related thing I can find is the [known BS4 / mod_wsgi bug with xml](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/948577). Not what I am seeing. There also don't seem to be any open bugs in the BeautifulSoup launchpad site related to my issue.

On a Red Hat VM (Enterprise Linux, 6.3), I am running Python 2.6.6 / Django 1.6.2, and Apache with mod_wsgi. I am using BeautifulSoup 4 to create a simple XML document. About half the time this fails and an empty XML document is created. `self` is a class that has a structure like:

```
self.my_original_object = instance of class MyObjects
self.my_original_object._my_map = nested dict of attributes
```

where:

```
def has_text(self, label):
    if label in self.my_original_object._my_map['texts']:
        return True
    return False

def get_text(self, label):
    if self.has_text(label):
        return self.my_original_object._my_map['texts'][label]
    raise IllegalState()
```

Onto the buggy code:

```
import logging
logging.info(self.get_text('body'))
soup = BeautifulSoup('<problem><p>' + self.get_text('body') + '</p></problem>', ['lxml','xml'])
problem = soup.find('problem')
logging.info(soup)
problem['display_name'] = question['displayName']['text']
```

In my logs, I see either soup or no soup, inconsistently -- I continually refresh the webpage, and sometimes I get the right data, sometimes an exception.

Bad result `(self.get_text('body') == 'what??')`:

```
INFO 2014-11-06 11:44:43,359 item_records 60428 139914916681696 what??
INFO 2014-11-06 11:44:43,359 item_records 60428 139914916681696 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
INFO 2014-11-06 11:44:43,360 utilities 60428 139914916681696 An exception of type TypeError occurred in assessments.views.ItemTextAsFormat.get(). Arguments:
("'NoneType' object does not support item assignment",)
```

Expected result:

```
INFO 2014-11-06 11:43:07,917 item_records 58188 139914916681696 what??
INFO 2014-11-06 11:43:07,918 views 58188 139914916681696 <problem display_name="test" max_attempts="0" rerandomize="never" showanswer="closed">
 <p>
  what??
 </p>
 <multiplechoiceresponse>
  <choicegroup direction="vertical">
   <choice correct="true" name="Choice 1">
    <text>
     1
    </text>
   </choice>
   <choice correct="false" name="Choice 2">
    <text>
     2
    </text>
   </choice>
  </choicegroup>
 </multiplechoiceresponse>
</problem>
```

I can re-work the code to construct the initial XML doc piecemeal, and that seems to work fine:

```
import logging
logging.info(self.get_text('body'))
soup = BeautifulSoup('<problem></problem>', ['lxml','xml'])
p = soup.new_tag('p')
problem = soup.find('problem')
p.string = self.get_text('body')
problem.append(p)
logging.info(soup)
problem['display_name'] = question['displayName']['text']
```

Downgrading to BeautifulSoup 3 also seems to fix the issue, so I have multiple workarounds. Just curious if others have seen anything similar or if I should be using BS4 differently to construct an XML doc.

Comment: If this is a race condition: As a stop-gap fix I suggest you use only processes, not threads, when serving with `mod_wsgi`. Processes, by the definition, cannot share any state so the race condition should go away. Then go through your code carefully and make sure there is no global state shared anywhere.

Comment: If this is a timing issue (e.g. by waiting data from the socket): it gets complicated.